Let $a,b,c \ge 0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ prove that $\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+b} \ge abc + 2$
Let $a,b,c \ge 0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ prove that: $$\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+b} \ge abc + 2$$
I have a solution but it's not really nice.
This is my solution:
First, we prove: $$\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+b} \ge \sqrt{8\sum_{cyc} a-4}$$
Taking square bothside, we prove $$\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)} \ge 3\sum_{cyc} a -2$$
Using Minkowski inequality, we have: $$\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)} = \sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a^2+\sum_{cyc} ab} \ge \sqrt{(\sum_{cyc} a)^2 +9 \sum_{cyc} ab}$$
Let $\sum_{cyc} a=x$, we have $1 \le x \le \sqrt{3}$ and $\sum_{cyc} ab = \frac{x^2-1}{2}$. we need to prove
$$\sqrt{x^2+\frac{9(x^2-1)}{2}} \ge 3x-2 \iff 11x^2-9\ge2(9x^2-12x+4)\iff7x^2-24x+17\ge 0\iff(7x-17)(x-1)\ge0$$
which is true because $1\le x\le\sqrt{3}$
Back to the question, we need to prove that $\sqrt{8\sum_{cyc} a-4}\ge 2+abc \iff 8\sum_{cyc} a\ge 8+4abc +a^2b^2c^2\iff 8\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{ab}}\ge 8 +4abc+a^2+b^2+c^2$
Because $0 \le a,b,c \le 1$ so $0 \le abc \le 1$ so $a^2b^2c^2 \le abc \le \sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2} \le \sum_{cyc} ab$. Therefore $8+4abc +a^2b^2c^2 \le 8 + 5abc$
We just need to prove:
$8\sqrt{1+2\sum_{cyc} ab} \ge 8 +5abc \iff 64 + 128\sum_{cyc} ab \ge64 + 80abc + 25a^2b^2c^2 \iff 128\sum_{cyc} ab \ge 80abc +25a^2b^2c^2$. This is true
I'm seeking an alternative solution now. I apologize if my previous suggestion was incorrect. If you can, please suggest improvements. Thanks!

I think you have a notation error. What does $\sum \sqrt{a+b}$ mean?

@Gwen In my school, i learned that $\sum \sqrt{a+b} = \sqrt{a+b} + \sqrt{b+c} + \sqrt{c+a}$

Oh you meant cyclic summation? Then you can add subscript of "cyc" like this $\sum_{cyc}$

@Gwen Thanks a lot, i will edit my question

From the given hypothesis, it is clear that $1\ge a, b, c \ge 0 $. WLOG, assume $1\ge a \ge b \ge c \ge 0 $. So, we have
$$\sqrt{b+c} \ge \sqrt{2\sqrt{bc}} =\sqrt[4]{4bc} \ge abc$$
since $a^4b^3c^3 <4$.
Now,
$$(a+b)(a+c)=a^2+ab+bc+ca \ge a^2+b^2+c^2 =1$$
implying
$$\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a+c} \ge 2$$
hence completing the proof.

Thanks, but could you please explain in more detail why $\sqrt[4]{4bc} \ge abc$ because $a^4b^3c^3 <4$?

Take $4>a^4 b^3 c^3$, multiply by $bc$ and take fourth root on both sides.

$$\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+b} \ge 2+abc$$
$$\iff2(a+b+c) +\sum_{cyc}2\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}\ge a^2b^2c^2+4abc+4$$
Using B-C-S inequality, we have:
$$\sum_{cyc}2\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)} \ge 2(a+b+c+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca})$$
We need to prove:
$$2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca})\ge5abc$$
It's true because $abc\le1$ so $2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca})\ge 6\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge5a bc$
